# How can I query a table based on bits in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subject] (
    [SubjectId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Type] BINARY(10) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Subject] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SubjectId] ASC)
);
```

My thinking is that the Type column would contain a binary string like this:

```
0000101010 
1000001010
0000001011
1000000011
```

What I would then like to be able to do is to for example query this table to look for particular bit being set but I am not sure how to do this. So for example how could I query the data to see what rows matched the fourth bit (from right) being set to a 1 and the second bit (from right) being set to a 1 which would result in three rows returned from the data above.

Comment: Are you aware that your declaration is for an 11-byte field for `Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend doing bit fiddling unless you really know what you are doing.

Normally, flags that are `tinyint` are quite sufficient for most purposes.  However, if you have a bunch of binary flags and are very concerned about space, then declare them each independently:

```
Flag1 bit not null,
Flag2 bit not null,
. . .
```

This gives a name to each "bit" and let's the database manage the bit fiddling.

In any case, the answer to your specific question are the bit-wise operators, which are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can query your data using bitwise operators in SQL.

See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

```
Something like 

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type & 0x0001000 > 0
```

You may have to experiment with the constant you use to `AND` against (0x0001000).  But this is saying - get me all records where the fourth bit from the right is a 1.   (0x prefix denotes a binary representation)